# [TCL]how to remove some of the paths in auto_path

Tags: tcl

I've got too much path in auto_path,how to remove some of the paths? what's the command?

[image]

Comment: Why is it too many? And do you want to remove them for just the current session or permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are no particular reasons to do that, having too many paths in `auto_path` global variable is not a problem... anyway you can try this procedure just as a proof of concept:

```
proc DelFromAutoPath { item } {
    global auto_path
    set pos [lsearch -exact $auto_path $item]
    if { $pos >= 0 } {
        set auto_path [lreplace $auto_path $pos $pos]
    }
}
```

Call the procedure somewhere in your code (but why?) or shell to remove the given path from list (if exists):

```
DelFromAutoPath "D:/lab/ata-switch-comservermerge/exec/lib"
```

**Remember:** it's not a permanent setting, the above will work just for current session or script.

If you need a permanent solution (if even possible), I believe this depends on your TCL distribution or platform, I cannot help you here. Bye.